# What function in Lisp allows you to compare variable names and not what it holds?

Tags: binding, lisp, common-lisp

Note: First time using lisp*

I have a homework, and we are suppose to essentially bind expressions with either a 0 or 1. Example:

```
(defun orexp (a b) (list 'or a b))

(setq p3 (orexp 1 'a)) ;which equals (or 1 a)
```

Say I wanted to create a function to evaluate them by binding them and simplify them, but ignoring the simplification, how can I bind them doing something like this:

```
(evalexp p3 '((a 0)))
```

and end up with:

```
(or 1 0)
```

I tried searching it, but I can't find anything. Please let me know if it needs a better explanation, but I am leaving information out because its a homework and I do not want answers, hints on how to go about my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the title, you say you want to compare symbols (what you call variable names).

```
> (eq 'a 'a)
true
> (eq 'a 'b)
false
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't doing that compare whats inside of it?

Comment: Well actually, can you compare variable names?

Comment: Yes, you can compare symbols in lisp.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare symbols with `eq`.

Your function is something like `(defun evalexp (expression bindings) #| ... |#)`, where
the commented part (`#| ... |#`) would contain your code.  It would have to walk the `expression` tree, and for each symbol it finds, check whether a binding of that symbol exists in `bindings`, replacing the symbol with the value when that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, eq is implementation-dependent on its specificity isn't it?:

> The effect is that Common Lisp makes no guarantee that eq is true even when both its arguments are ``the same thing'' if that thing is a character or number.
>   (from the hyperspec)

So eq should work if you quote the arguments, involved, but I think you could write a small little macro to do what you want without hand-quoting if you wanted:

```
(defmacro es (x y)
          `(eq (quote ,x) (quote ,y)))
```

works I think.

Comment: Since the question is about symbols in the same package, this is irrelevant.